# Command are running manually, but cron is not running

Tags: cron, cron-job

I'm running CiviCRM 5.32.0 on WordPress 5.6 hosted by Hostinger.

1st step I test cv.phar =
php /xzy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cv.phar api Job.process_mailing --user=abcd --cwd=/xyz

2nd step I test a script using that command with the same result OK =
bash civicron_2.sh
{
"is_error": 0,
"version": 3,
"count": 1,
"id": "processed",
"values": {
"processed": 0
}
}

3nd step, I created the cron rule in Hostinger panel (every 30 minutes) =
0,30 * * * *    /usr/bin/php /xyz/abcd/civicron_2.sh

But finaly CiviCRM UI says : "no cron job is running" and the only way I succed to run Job is manually on the CiviCRM UI.

I need advice to go further.
BR hervé

Comment: I tried the wp-cli methode with the same result = -bash-4.1$ /xzy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/wp-cli.phar --user=abcd --url=https://cycloclubbreuillet.fr --cwd=/xzy civicrm api job.execute auth=0
Array
(
    [is_error] => 0
    [version] => 3
    [count] => 1
    [values] => 1
)

Comment: You'll need to figure out where the error is being captured. Since it looks like you're using the system cron, the error will likely be in /var/log/syslog. However, since you have a hosted account, I'm not really sure exactly where. I am confident however, that there will be useful information from cron in the log.

Comment: I reply to myself to explain the first part of my solution: **the current working directory was incorrect**.
Using wp-cli methode the parametre of --cwd= must not be the directory where index.php of the website is located (in my case /home/u781989671/public_html/) but the directory where all directories of the website are located (in my case /home/u781989671/)
Now, when I run the new script in command-line PuTTY, I can see in UI CiviCRM that cron has been executed.
The second part of the solution has to be found with suport Hostinger.
I created a rule in UI Hostinger but noting happens.

Comment: Ok, I solve the second part of the solution: I have to put the command directly in the Hostinger cron panel and not the path to file including the command. best regards rv

Comment: CiviCRM will tell you "cron is not running" unless your cron calls "Job.execute". Calling a specific job like "Job.process_mailing" is OK, but it will not appear in the Scheduled Jobs Log and CiviCRM will not see it as "cron is running".

Comment: If you have found a solution that you're satisfied with, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to close this post, I'll explain the solution.
There were 2 mistakes:
1/ the parametre cwd= (current working directory)  was incorrect.
2/ the way I use UIHostinger for cron was incorect.

My solution is:
`0,30 * * * *   /usr/bin/php /home/u781989671/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cv.phar api job.execute --user=myuser --cwd=/home/u781989671/public_html`

best regards,
rv